# FontAwesome Stacking Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: font-awesome

link:  http://perlabeautysalon.com

Im trying to create a square background (with font awesome) and stack a users icon on top of it.. however, for some reason.. it wont display right..  one icon is below the other...

heres my code

```
<span class="fa-stack" style="color:#EA5555">
<i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-users fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you code is fine, I'm just not sure why you have "br" tags:

```
<span style="color:#EA5555" class="fa-stack"><br>
  <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i><br>
  <i class="fa fa-users fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i><br>
</span>
```

When I remove them in your site using Firebug - the icon seems to be what you need.